# Lightbox no AngularJs 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, lightbox

Ainda sou bem inexperiente com o AngularJs e por isso travo em coisas simples.

Estou precisando usar o **Lightbox** em um projeto. *"Googlando"* por aí, achei o [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox), mas daí me deparei com a situação em que toda a documentação dele é para **AngularJS 1.x** e estou usando no meu projeto o **AngularJS 2**, fazendo uso de **Typescript**.

Alguém pode me ajudar em como devo fazer para usá-lo no **AngularJS 2**?

Answer (score 1):

O Angular 2 trouxe um modelo totalmente diferente para a construção de aplicações Single Page. Não dá para você usar a diretiva do Lightbox para AngularJS 1 que você linkou aí acima diretamente no Angular 2. Até mesmo o conceito de diretivas mudou, enfim, tudo mudou.

Você só tem duas opções, ao meu ver: ou criar seu próprio componente do Lightbox com Angular 2 ou esperar que alguém faça esse componente por você. Aliás, fazer componentes no Angular 2 é até mais fácil do que fazer Diretivas no AngularJS, por que não tentar? :)